# ASP.NET site, format string attack on dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, security, zap

I'm using OWASP ZAP software to test a simple asp.net site for vulnerability. I'm getting a medium alert of Format String Attack type that I'm not understanding well.
In details I'm getting these informations:

Description: A Format String error occurs when the submitted data of an input string is evaluated as a command by the application.

URL: `http://example.com/page.aspx`

Parameter: `ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24dropType`

Attack: ZAP

Solution: Rewrite the background program using proper deletion of bad character strings. This will require a recompile of the background executable.

Other information: Potential Format String Error. The script closed the connection on a /%s

Reference: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Format_string_attack

The ddl is like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropType" runat="server" >
    <asp:ListItem Value="A" Text="SIMPLE A TEXT"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="B" Text="SIMPLE B TEXT"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="C" Text="SIMPLE C TEXT"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and initially I thought that the problem was getting the value from that, so I change the code from:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", dropType.SelectedItem.Text)
```

to:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", Regex.Replace(dropType.SelectedItem.Text, "[^\w\.@-]",""))
```

but recompiling and rerunning the test, I'm still getting the alert. Then I try commenting that entire line of code, just for test, but compiling and rerunning the test I still having the alert. Is a false positive, considering that now I've just a simple dropdownlist in the aspx page without references to that in the code?

**UPDATE:**

If I add a page, page2.aspx, with the same ddl, I'm getting no vulnerability alert on it. The only difference with the other page with the same dll that's causing the alert is that there are no reference to page2.aspx in other pages, but in some pages there are instead link to page.aspx, the page of the alert:

```
<a href="../page.aspx">
    <img src="../img/image.jpg" />
</a>
```

So I think that the alert in some way is about that..

Comment: Are you sure this is about the dropdown list?  Your description (above) doesn't specifically identify a dropdown list.  Also, the fact that you moved it to another page, makes it seem that OWASP might have been complaining about something else on that page.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I don't have moved it to another page, just replicated it. In the Parameter field of the alert I've the id of the ddl (dropType). If I run the test without the ddl, I don't have the alert... I've the alert if I have the ddl, and in another page a link pointing to the page with the ddl..

Comment: Are you using C? If not, then this is a false positive.

Comment: No, I'm using vb.net, and I think is a false positive too. A workaround for not having the alert is change the link to the page with an ImageButton with a Response.Redirect in the OnClick function..

Comment: No, the workaround is not working, still getting the alert, with the ImageButton too. I think that I'm going to ignore it.